# setting make variable (FreeBSD 9.3) on if condition

Tags: makefile, freebsd

I am trying to redo part of the Makefile we use for building NAS, I am having trouble setting `SEQUENCE` to `${TRAIN}-${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}` when update server is defined. I use the following command to build.

`env UPDATE_INTERNAL=yes build/release.sh NAS yes`

```
ENV_SETUP+= NANO_LABEL=${NANO_LABEL}
ENV_SETUP+= VERSION=${VERSION}
ENV_SETUP+= BUILD_TIMESTAMP=${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}
ENV_SETUP+= SEQUENCE=${NANO_LABEL}-${RELEASE_IDENTIFIER}-RELEASE
ENV_SETUP+= TRAIN=${TRAIN}
ENV_SETUP+= UPDATE_USER=${UPDATE_USER}
ENV_SETUP+= UPDATE_HOST=${UPDATE_HOST}
ENV_SETUP+= FREENAS_KEYFILE=${FREENAS_KEYFILE}
.if exists(ChangeLog)
ENV_SETUP+= CHANGELOG=ChangeLog
.endif

.if defined(UPDATE_INTERNAL)
SEQUENCE=${TRAIN}-${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}
UPDATE_USER?=vb-int
UPDATE_HOST?=vb-update-int.yyyyy.xxxxx.com
POST_TO_DOWNLOAD=no
.else
UPDATE_USER?=xxx
UPDATE_HOST?=update.something.org
POST_TO_DOWNLOAD=yes
.endif
```

I am editing to include o/p of the command

`env _KEY=set NANO_LABEL=NAS VERSION=9.3-STABLE BUILD_TIMESTAMP=201602092045 SEQUENCE=NAS-9.3.2-RELEASE TRAIN=NAS-9.3-STABLE UPDATE_USER=......`

Comment: What output do you see? Is there an error? What does `make -V` print?

Comment: And your question is? When you go to the doctor, say more than "ouch!"